# Sending a mail using PHP

Tags: php, email

I have a piece of code which upon approval sends a mail to an email address. The email is not being sent. Do I need to configure something on my web server?

```
function mailpassword($email, $password){
    //notify that the password has been changed
    mysqli_select_db($connect,"members");

    $query = "select email from users where email = '".$email."'";
    $mailquery = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    if(!$mailquery)
    {
        throw new Exception ('The entered email address could not be found');
    }
    else if($mailquery->num_rows==0)
    {
        throw new Exception ('The entered email address could not be found');

        //username not in database
    }
    //if no errors, send mail
    else
    {
        $row = $mailquery->fetch_object();
        $email = $row->email;
        $from = "From : support@example.com \r\n";
        $mesg = "Hey,\n\n You requested for a new password. We have generated a completely random password for you, use it to login.\n\n
        New Password - ".$password."\r\n
        Please change this random password to a password of your choice once you log in. To change your password, click on the Accounts tab present in your dashboard.\r\n

        Cheers\r\n
        Hap";

        if(mail($email, 'Password Change Account Details', $mesg, $from))
        {
            return true;
            echo "great";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Something went wrong";
        }
    }

    $mails = mailpassword();
}
```

Comment: You could test without the `$from` field however. It contains extraneous whitespace before the `:` and the `\r\n` (which should be omitted too if it's the last/only header).

Comment: @mario - good point, noted. I'll do that in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy solution to email problems: use a hosted solution that makes sure all email sent from your application gets through. There are some alternatives like [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/). We use Postmark with great success (not affiliated though ehe;)

There's this [PHP class for Postmark](https://github.com/Znarkus/postmark-php) that I'm kinda proud of... :-)

This wasn't directly an answer to your question, but I hope it was helpful anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the space before the colon in the From header:

```
$from = "From: support@example.com \r\n"
```